# How can I call a program using php and take the data in a text field and pass as an argument from a HTML site?

Tags: php, html, perl

How can I call a program using PHP and take the data in a text field and pass as an argument from a HTML site?

I have a program named "sign". It is an executable perl script that when run `/usr/bin/messagesign $0` will output to a LED scrolling marquee.

This all works perfectly from the terminal. I want to embed this in a web site. I am creating a mancave with a bar and I want this to be so I can change the message of what's on tap from a web page. It's not going to be public facing so I don't care about security.

Comment: This is quite broad, have you tried anything, done any research? Please see [help/on-topic], [ask].

Comment: i know how to run a script from a web page that runs an application.   I guess my real question is, how do i pass text from a textbox in a web page back to the python script